# Nested "this" binding in ES6 classes using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, this, es6-class

Reading through React docs I came across the [following piece of code](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class):

```js
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Clock />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My question is this:

In `componentDidMount()` the arrow function `() => this.tick()` "captures" the enclosing `this` value and thus the proper `tick` method is called on the `<Clock>` component.

**However** `tick` uses `this` on its own to subsequently call the `setState` method. How is this working without any bindings? In other words, how is `this.setState` working?

Thanks

Comment: `()=>` actually binds current this to function. Its similar to `function(){}.bind(this)`. You can also try `setTimeout(this.tick.bind(this), 1000)`

Comment: @Rajesh What you are suggesting only applies to `this.tick`. Inside the `tick` method however `this` **is used again** to call `setState`. That's the `this` that troubles me the most.

Comment: What do you think would `this` hold in `tick`?

Comment: @Rajesh I believe that `this` within the `tick` function should be undefined or the global Object/window. Not a react component though...

Comment: For clarity on `this`, refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work. A simple explanation, a function's this points to callee(*instance associated with it*) or default(*window or undefined*). Now when you do `()=>`, you are binding `this` of `componentDidMount` to `tick`, which points to `component. Hence setState works fine

Comment: hope it solves your query. If not, feel free to ask. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`bind` function documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#The_bind_method), `Function.prototype.bind` will create a new function with the same body and scope as the original function, but where `this` in the scope of the new function refers to the argument that is passed into `bind`. This means you can pass a variable, lets say `newContext` into the `bind` function like: `tick.bind(newContext)`, and every instance of `this` inside of tick will be evaluated as `newContext`. Although `this` is a keyword referring to the context of the scope, we have changed the scope's context and so `this` has a different value.

The arrow notation does something similar, and will replace the `this` inside the value `tick` with the value of the context of the arrow function's scope. This is why the `this` keyword inside of `tick` does not have an `undefined` value.

Answer (score 1):

I think Rajesh has already explained it in the comments, still I will give it a try to explain.

An arrow function does not create its own this context, so this has its original meaning from the enclosing context i.e from where it is being called which is `componentDidMount` in your case.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    // this refers to React.Component instance
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),  // <----------------Same this is available here
      1000
    );
  }
```

If you use bind you can achieve similar things via setting context via bind.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    // this refers to React.Component instance from inside cdm method
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      this.tick.bind(this),  // <----------------Same this is available here
     // We have set it react component instance via bind
      1000
    );
  }
```

Now after all those just look only at this method declaration -

```
  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    });
  }
```

Upto this point we can not say exactly what will be the value of `this` inside `tick`. 
We also can not say that '`setState`' will be available on `this` or not.

Unless and until we see from where `tick` will get called and what **execution context** will be attached to `tick` at **run time**.

Now if we see from where tick is getting called - `componentDidMount`.
`componentDidMount` is react component's life cycle method and it ( associated context i.e this) definitely has `setState` method available.

And in `componentDidMount` we had set `this` to `react-component` context either via arrow function `() => {}` or via `bind`.
This is the reason because of which `setState` is avaialble in `tick` when called and you don't see any error.

But if you don't use **arrow function** or **explicit bind** you will be receiving following error on each time when `setInterval` calls `tick` function there by associating a global this with tick.

```
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function",
```

See the below code snippet via running to see the error

```js
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // now this inside tick will be pointing to setIntervals execution context which could be global
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      this.tick,
      1000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Clock />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
</div>
```